# What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition. Can anybody explain briefly?

Tags: verilog

I tried to figure out the inferred latch and why it is needed internally, but I couldn't find any resources with enough detail.

Comment: Perhaps you could include links to where you have already looked, so people don't suggest what you have already tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036401/if-statements-causing-latch-inference-in-verilog

Answer (score 25):

A latch is inferred within a combinatorial block where the net is not assigned to a known value. Assign a net to itself will still infer a latch. Latches can also be inferred by missing signals form a sensitivity list and feedback loops.

The proper way of inferring a intended latch in Verilog/SystemVerilog are:

```
/* Verilog */       ////    /* SystemVerilog */
always @*           ////    always_latch
begin               ////    begin
  if (en) q = d;    ////      if (en) q = d;
end                 ////    end
```

### Ways latches are accidentally inferred:

- Signal(s) missing for the sensitivity list (this is why `@*` should be used):

  ```
  always @(a or b) // inferred latch :: "c" missing for the sensitivity list.
  begin
    out = a + b + c;
  end
  ```
- Missing Condition:

  ```
  always @*
  begin
    case(in[1:0])
     2'b00:  out = 1'b0;
     2'b01:  out = 1'b1;
     2'b10:  out = 1'b1;
     // inferred latch "out" :: missing condition 2'b11/default
   endcase
  end
  always @*
  begin
    next0 = flop0;
    next1 = flop1;
    // inferred latch "next2" :: missing initial condition
    next3 = flop3;
    case(a[2:0])
     3'b001:             next0 = in;
     3'b010:  if(b)      next1 = in;
     3'b100:  if(c)      next2 = in;
     default: if(!b&&!c) next3 = in;
   endcase   
  end
  ```
- Feedback Loop:

  ```
  assign out = en ? in : out; // inferred latch "out" :: feedback to mux
  assign a = en ? z : c;
  // ... any amount of code between ...
  assign z = en ? a : y; // inferred latch "a" :: feedback chain
  ```

  - Feedback loops can traverse through the hierarchy and design.

### How to mitigate the risk of unintended latches:

- Make intended latches simple and identifiable:

  - Put intended latches in their own always blocks with as little combinatorial logic as possible; ideally put the latches' combinatorial logic in its own separate always block. Be as explicit and identify intended latches. Use comments, labels, and if possible use the SystemVerilog `always_latch`.
- All combinatorial logic blocks need to be defined with `always @*` or SystemVerilog's `always_comb`.
- Make sure all variables assigned in a combinatorial logic blocks have an initial or default assignment.

  - `case` statements should have a `default` condition.
  - `if` statements should have a corresponding `else`.
  - When the combinatorial logic blocks is assigning many variables, giving each variable an initial value at the start of the block (before any `case` or `if`).
- Know where the inputs are coming from and where the outputs are going to.

  - The inputs of combinatorial logic should be flops **or** the outputs combinatorial logic should be flops.
- Do code reviews, use linting tools and logical-equivalency-checking tools.

  - Code review requires the reviewer(s) to know where latches could hide.
  - Using SystemVerilog's `always_comb` can help identify inferred latches with linting and logical-equivalency-checking tools.

Worst case scenario, put all logic inside synchronous blocks. All inferred latches become inferred flip-flops. This is usually a bad idea because it can unnecessarily increases the gate count, create more routing, and impact timing.

Comment: I think `always_latch` should be added as a correct way to imply in SystemVerilog

Comment: @Morgan, your suggestion has been added to my answer

Answer (score 8):

A latch is inferred when the output of combinatorial logic has undefined states, that is it must hold its previous value.

Combinatorial logic does not have any flip-flop to hold state therefore the output should always be defined by the inputs.

A short example might be:

```
always @* begin
  if (a == 1'b1) begin
    b =  x|y|z;
  end
end
```

What is `b` when `a == 1'b0`. `b` is not being overridden so it would hold its value. How can something hold its value when it does not have the concept of state. You have to introduce state by inferring a latch. This is normally a really bad thing.

You can imply latches and be carefull about the timing etc but inferred latches are nominally from buggy code.

Answer (score 3):

Latches are only generated with combinational always blocks. Sequential logic will never generate a latch.

For more information read about [how transparent latches are created and how to avoid inferring latches](http://www.nandland.com/articles/how-to-avoid-transparent-latches-in-vhdl-and-verlog.html)