# second if loop is not working in verilog and latches are generated .how to fix these?

Tags: verilog

I'm new to Verilog. I tried the below code calling the 'task' into a if loop.. Syntax is correct. But when I execute behavioral simulation with `choice` as 010 the loop is not working. The output is shown all zeroes and the synthesis report shows latches are generated..How to fix these two.

```
module a(choice,data1,data2,result);
  input[2:0]choice;
  input[6:0]data1;
  input[8:0]data2;
  output[8:0]result;

  reg[8:0]reg_result;

  wire[3:0]choice;
  wire[6:0]data1;
  wire[8:0]data2;
  wire[8:0]result;

  initial///initailllllllllllllllllllllllllll
  begin
    reg_result=0; //declaring output register to 0 initially
  end

  always @(data1 or data2 or choice )
  begin
    if(choice==001)////if loop 1
    begin
      taskoperation(data1,reg_result);///load result from task 
    end
    if(choice==010)//when choice is given as 010 the simulated output gives me all    
    begin//zeroes in   result(output reg) 
      taskoperation(data2,reg_result);
    end
  end
  //task operation
  task taskoperation(
    input [8:0]datainput;
    output [8:0]dataoutput
  );
    dataoutput[8:0]=~(datainput[8:0]);//taskoperation
  endtask

  assign result=reg_result;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

**Latches**

The latches are probably generated due to your use of 2 `if` statements as selectors. These should be [case](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/vbehave2.html) statements.

```
case (choice) 
 3'b001 : 
     begin
         taskoperation(data1,reg_result);
     end 
 3'b010 : 
     begin
         taskoperation(data2,reg_result);
     end
 default : $display("Error in choice");  //Know when there are other issues!
 endcase
```

**Why is 010 not working?**

See how in my case statement I use `3'b001` and `3'b010` to represent the cases? By including the size prefix `3` I indicate how many bits I need that bus to be. By including the `b` I indicate that I want my numbers to be interpreted as binary values. So `3'b001` is equivalent to the decimal value `1`. Likewise `3'b010` is interpreted as 2. If I just write `010` without any prefix, the compiler thinks I am talking about a decimal value and interprets it as a `10` in decimal. That is where you were probably going wrong. The `010` case was simply never being reached. Moral of the story always write prefixes when coding in literals!

**Notes**

Note that `if` you do think if statements are the right tool for the job make sure to ALWAYS include an `else` block to avoid latch generation.

Literals: http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax1.html

Another `case` reference: http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00004.htm

And finally a beginners reference on why latches happen: http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verifaq2.html

Answer (score 0):

`010` is inferred as a decimal, making it the value ten. Define it with Boolean base literal; `3'b010`. you should also correct `001` to `3'b001`.

The SystemVerilog follows the same rule. This is the definition from [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*

> *Integer literal* constants can be specified in decimal, hexadecimal, octal, or binary format.
>   There are two forms to express integer literal constants. The first form is a simple decimal number, which shall be specified as a sequence of digits `0` through `9`, optionally starting with a plus or minus unary operator. The second form specifies a *based literal constant*, which shall be composed of up to three tokens—an optional size constant, an apostrophe character (', ASCII 0x27) followed by a base format character, and the digits representing the value of the number. It shall be legal to macro-substitute these three tokens.

The latch is being caused for two reasons:

1. `choice==010` means `{29'b0,choice}==32'd10` which is never true and will be optimized out durring sunthesis.
2. There is no `else` condition when choice is not 1 or 2. This means `reg_result` will keep its value. Since this in in combinatorial logic, a latch is inferred.

Turn `if(choice==010)` to `else if(choice==2'b010)` and add an `else` condition assigning `reg_result` a value.

Fix the syntax error: `input [8:0]datainput;` needs to be `input [8:0]datainput,` (semicolon to comma).

---

Other suggestions:

- Use `always @*` instead of `@(data1 or data2 or choice)` unless you are required to follow strict Verilog95 standards. Using `@*` can help prevent inferred latches when the sensitivity list is long. Refer to [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition.can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i)
- Use functions instead of tasks whenever possible when intending to synthesize. Tasks allow time blocking which is not synthesizable.
- Use ANSI style port declarations. Non-ANSI style is required only for Verilog95. Example:

  ```
  module a(
  input      [2:0] choice,
  input      [6:0] data1,
  input      [8:0] data2,
  output reg [8:0] result );
  ```

ANSI-style is supported from Verilog-2001.

Answer (score 0):

Latches are generated any time you have a non-sequential block (any always block which does not have a @posedge or @negedge in the sensitivity list), and there is a possible code path in the RTL which results in a signal retaining its old value.

Example:

```
if (foo)
  bar = 1;
// no else
```

In this case, a latch will be inferred because if foo == 0 then bar will retain its value (it is stateful).  To fix this, either use an else:

```
if (foo)
  bar = 1;
else
  bar = ~fred;
```

Or, if your decision tree is complicated, assign a default value and override it later:

```
bar = ~fred;
if (foo)
  bar = 1;
```

The latter is frequently used with state machines, where it can be difficult to make sure you have a full case/if/else tree for every signal.