# Why does an If statement cause a latch in verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to code a controller/data-path implementation in Verilog, and I am confused on what will cause an unwanted latch. Essentially, I have a state machine updating on the negedge clock. This state machine sends 5 control signals (loadSquare, loadDelta, addDelta, etc.) to the data-path based on what state the machine is in. The code for the data-path and controller is shown below.

**Data-path**

```
//Control lines
reg addSquare, addDelta, decDelta;
reg loadSquare, loadDelta;

//Input lines
reg [8:0] square, delta;

//Output register
reg [7:0] outReg;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (loadSquare)
     square = 9'h1;  //used on initialization

  if (loadDelta)
     delta = 9'h3;   //used on initialization

  if (addSquare)
     square = square + delta; 

  if (addDelta)
     delta = delta + 2'h2;

  if (decDelta)
     outReg = (delta>>1) - 1;  //used for output
  else
     outReg = Input;
end
```

**Controller**

```
//Output of module
assign Output = outReg;

//Finite State Machine
always @(currentState) begin
    case(currentState)
        2'h0:   begin       //initialize values, wait for start
        {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b11;
        {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'h0;
     end
        2'h1: begin
        {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
        {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b110;  //add square and delta
     end
        2'h2: begin
        {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
        {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b001;  //decrement delta, wait for reset
     end
        default: ; // unused
    endcase

//Next state logic implemented on negedge clk (not shown)
```

This code generates the following warnings in Xilinx:

```
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <addDelta>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <decDelta>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <loadDelta>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:1294 - Latch <loadDelta> is equivalent to a wire in block <ModuleName>.
WARNING:Xst:1294 - Latch <decDelta> is equivalent to a wire in block <ModuleName>.
WARNING:Xst:1294 - Latch <addDelta> is equivalent to a wire in block <ModuleName>.
```

I understand that incomplete if statements cause latches. In order to try to account for this, I have tried 2 different implementations but they do not remove the warnings. I am especially confused for the "decDelta" case because I don't understand what I am not accounting for in this conditional statement.

**Try #1**

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (loadSquare)
     square = 9'h1;
  else
     square = square;

  if (loadDelta)
     delta = 9'h3;
  else
     delta = delta;

  //... and so on
```

**Try #2**

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  square = square;
  delta = delta;

  if (loadSquare)
     square = 9'h1;

  if (loadDelta)
     delta = 9'h3;

  //... and so on
```

The code works as expected when I run a simulation, but I wanted to learn a little more about what causes these warnings.

Comment: For `always @(posedge clk)` you should be using `<=` non-blocking assignments to correctly simulate a flip-flop.

Comment: Can you show how `addDelta` is driven/

Comment: Make sure there is an "else" statement for an "if". Latches are created, if you dont specify the state of signal under some condition. So make sure you mention all the cases.

Comment: You are showing us the wrong process. We need the process(es) which drive these 3 signals. There is no error in the process where these signals are used/read.

Comment: @Paebbels, The controller code has been added.

Comment: @Morgan, The reason I did not use `<=` is because I was unsure how the default values in **Try 2** would be loaded. Can you clarify if there would be an issue with regards to the timing. I have a limited understanding of how conditional statements are evaluated when used at the same level of non-blocking assignments. If `<=` is used, will the default values be loaded before the `if` statements? If not, will there be a problem when trying to modify the values if `if` evaluates true?

Comment: Only the last `<=` for a given register will be applied. Setting default then conditionally overriding is functionally the same as the if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A latch is a basic memory element, it is open or closed ie it is level sensitive. A flip-flop is basically two latches with one operating on the invert of the enable signal, this makes it edge sensitive.

When using `always @(posedge clk)` you have implied a flip-flop that loads data values on the rising edge of `clk`. Latches do not get implied inside this process (`always @(posedge clk)`).

As Sharvil111 has described latches are implied when you have left undefined states in combinatorial sections ie `always @*` processes. If some thing is undefined in part of a conditional then it retains its value. Value retention is state, and since combinatorial sections are not edge sensitive you have forced the tool to insert a latch.

To avoid this fully define the conditional output:

```
always @(currentState) begin
case(currentState)
    2'h0:   begin       //initialize values, wait for start
    {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b11;
    {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'h0;
 end
    2'h1: begin
    {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
    {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b110;  //add square and delta
 end
    2'h2: begin
    {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
    {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b001;  //decrement delta, wait for reset
 end
    default: begin
    {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
    {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b000;
    end
endcase
```

Answer (score 2):

Latches are inferred when a variable will have to **retain** its previous value, if it is **not assigned** a value in an always block. A latch must be created to **store** this present value.

*Latches* can cause various **race conditions**. Unwanted latches create a  feedback in a *combinational circuit*, i.e. it routes the output back to the input - which can be unpredictable causing unstable circuit behavior.

An **incomplete** `if-else` statement will generate unwanted latches. An if-else statement is considered "incomplete" if the one of the condition is not defined for all possible input conditions. Similarly, an incomplete `case` statement, that does not have a `default` statement can also infer to latch.

A **complete** `if-else` statement refers to the following Mux:

[image: Mux]

While and **incomplete** `if-else` refers to a *feedback path* from output to input, in order to **hold** the previous value. Similar applies to `case` statement.

[image: MuxLatch]

As a rule, combinational loops must be avoided:

> A general intention of a combinational circuit is that the output is a function of input only and the circuit should not contain any internal
>   state (i.e., memory).

As a *contradiction*, verilog standard specifies that a variable must retain/hold its *previous value* if it is not assigned a value in an always block. This is the root cause of latch creation.

To **avoid** the latches, following points must be kept in mind:

- Include **all** the branches of an `if` or `case` statement.
- Assign a value to **every output signal** in **every branch**.

Here, to avoid latch creation, either you can else branch and explicitly
assign all output variables, such that other input is *grounded*.

```
if (loadSquare)
     square <= 9'h1;  //used on initialization
else
     square <= 9'h0;  // similar for all the variables
```

Another *alternative* is to assign a *default* value at every clock tick.

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
square <= 9'h0;    // similar for all the variables
if (loadSquare)
     square <= 9'h1;  //used on initialization
end
```

**Side Note** : I've used *non-blocking* assignments statements here, for proper flip-flop synthesis.

For detailed synthesis information, refer to [FPGA prototyping by Verilog examples by Pong P. Chu](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjmnrzhz4zJAhXPG44KHfzDAAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffpga.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FFPGA%2520Prototyping%2520By%2520Verilog%2520Examples.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHWKu14n0aUrRsZUmcA3iajniogqA&sig2=C1jHt1_Qk2KUvFCQeTkmIQ&bvm=bv.107467506,d.d24) pdf. Also, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38645/why-are-inferred-latches-bad) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i) links about latch creation may be useful.

Image courtesy [doulous.com](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/synthesizing_latches/).

Comment: Clearing the register in every cycle except if `loadDelta` is high is not the intended behavior of the author. Note: the error is not caused by reading the process, it's caused by the process driving for ex. `addDelta`.

Comment: @downvoter. With utmost respect, I am focusing my answer to the lines.. **...and I am confused on what will cause an unwanted latch.** and OPs trial methods. Please don't consider it the other way.

Comment: @Paebbels, I am just explaining the reason of warnings and latch creation during synthesis. This has nothing to do with the `loadDelta` logic. In order to explain that, I've used the signal names provided by OP, a type of pseudo-code. I agree that warnings are occurring while **driving** those three signals,`addDelta`,`decDelta` etc. but right now my focus is only on the generalized cause of warnings.

Comment: @sharvil111, What would be the correct way to implement an `x = x + y` functionality without the use of latches? Would it be to declare a wire (ie. `assign x_wire = x + y` and then load the value on the wire into a register on a clock pulse? I have also added to controller code above.

Comment: @Anthony, A combinatorial loop is formed when the output of any gate is fed back to the input without passing through any sequential element. In this case, after getting value to `x_wire`, you'll ultimately use something like `always @(posedge clk) x <= x_wire;` to get value into `x`. [Here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/40068/what-is-a-typical-example-of-a-combinatorial-feedback-loop) is a similar query.

Answer (score 0):

The latches are cause by the state machine logic. The following always block is sensitive to `currentState` and not to a clock. This is not *bad*, but needs some extra precautions to hinder latch creation:

1. use a `default` case OR
2. use default assignments OR
3. use a different FSM pattern

Here is your code with my additions using default assignments:

```
//Finite State Machine
always @(currentState) begin
    // default assignments
    {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b0;
    {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'h0;        

    case(currentState)
      2'h0:   begin       //initialize values, wait for start
        {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b11;
        {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'h0;
      end
      2'h1: begin
        {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
        {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b110;  //add square and delta
      end
      2'h2: begin
        {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
        {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b001;  //decrement delta, wait for reset
      end
      default: ; // unused
    endcase

//Next state logic implemented on negedge clk (not shown)
```

For further information on latch creation have a look at @sharvil111's answer. He addresses this topic in a more general way.

Answer (score 0):

A latch is inferred when a variable within a combinational block is not assigned a value within all possible permutation of the blocks functionality.

```
case(currentState)
2'h0:   begin       //initialize values, wait for start
  {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b11;
  {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'h0;
end
2'h1: begin
  {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
  {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b110;  //add square and delta
end
2'h2: begin
  {loadSquare, loadDelta} = 2'b00;
  {addSquare, addDelta, decDelta} = 3'b001;  //decrement delta, wait for reset
end
default:  ; // unused // <-- not assigned so assumed keep; inferred latches
endcase
...
```

Doing something like `addSquare = addSquare;` is still an inferred latch. `addSquare` (and all the other variables) needs to be assigned to a constant, a flop (edge sensitive flip-flop), or combinational function terms of constants and flop values.

If you truly do not need `addSquare` (and all the other variables), then just assign them to a constant in the `default` condition.

If you do need to keep the value, then you need to add a flop that is synchrously assigned to the variable. In the `default` condition, the variable needs to be assigned to the flop. Example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  ...
  addSquare_keep <= addSquare;
  ...
end
always @* begin
  ...
  case(currentState)
  ...
  default : begin
    ...
    addSquare = addSquare_keep;
    ...
  end
  endcase
  ...
end
```