# Debugging error "procedural assignment to a non-register k is not permitted"

Tags: verilog, lookup-tables

My Verilog code looks like this. The module implements a look up table ROM with an address register that increments on a clock pulse. The output of this is decoded to give a 32 bit number. I don't see why k needs to be a register. In fact I don't want k to have a clocked delay after the address register changes. How is the decoding of `addr` meant to be specified?

(Note that seems unrelated to the similarly named other question on SO since I already checked that out - I don't want a register on the output. I just want to asynchronously decode the output of a count register. Maybe I'm confused about the <= operator which I assume will always generate a clocked register, but maybe I should always be using <=.)

```
module k_rom (input clk, input reset, output [31:0] k);
// Constants defined by the SHA-2 standard.
reg [5:0] addr;

always @ (addr)
    begin
        case(addr)
            6'h00: k = 32'h428a2f98;
            6'h01: k = 32'h71374491;
            6'h02: k = 32'hb5c0fbcf;
            6'h03: k = 32'he9b5dba5;
            6'h04: k = 32'h3956c25b;
            6'h05: k = 32'h59f111f1;
            6'h06: k = 32'h923f82a4;
            6'h07: k = 32'hab1c5ed5;
            6'h08: k = 32'hd807aa98;
            6'h09: k = 32'h12835b01;
            6'h0a: k = 32'h243185be;                                        
// other constants not shown for brevity
            6'h3c: k = 32'h90befffa; 
            6'h3d: k = 32'ha4506ceb; 
            6'h3e: k = 32'hbef9a3f7; 
            6'h3f: k = 32'hc67178f2;
        endcase
    end

always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        if(reset)
            addr <= 6'b0;
        else
            addr <= addr + 6'b1;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **LHS** of an assignment in a **procedural block** must be of type `reg`. Procedural assignment statements assign values to `reg`, `integer`, `real`, or `time` variables and *can not* assign values to `wire`. Note that `reg` can hold or store some value depending on some triggering event, while `wire` cannot store any value.

Here, `k` is **holding** some value till the `addr` signal changes. Henceforth, it needs to be `reg` type.

By default, the `output` signal is of type `wire`. Declare `k` as `output reg [31:0] k`.

```
module k_rom (input clk, input reset, output reg [31:0] k);
```

The use of blocking assignments (`=`) and nonblocking assignments (`<=`) seems to be correct in the above code.

Use blocking assignments (`=`) for **combinational logic** (the `always @(addr)` block). Use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for **sequential logic** (the `always @(posedge clk)` block).

But you may prefer to use `always @(*)` (or `always_comb` for SystemVerilog) instead of `always @(addr)` as an automatic sensitivity list.

Refer [this PDF](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/Documents/Nets.pdf) for knowing difference between `reg` and `wire`.

Comment: I guess a lot of my confusion came down to when will it generate a latch versus combinatorial logic: relating the hardware instantiation with the language constructs. Reg sounds like a register but I guess it is not. So if I understand, its actually just the fact that the sensitivity is posedge that generates an actual clocked latch? I seem to have found Verilog elsewhere that uses <= for combinatorial logic also.

Comment: This is a very wide topic for discussion. Refer [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/difference-between-blocking-and-nonblocking-assignment-verilog) for `=` and `<=` difference.

Comment: Latches create many timing and race around issues in the design. Latches are not only inferred from missing `posedge` stuff, but also due to missing `else` in `if..else` statement, missing `default` statement etc. Refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i) and [this link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38645/why-are-inferred-latches-bad) for basic idea about latches.

Comment: `reg` is a confusing term, it is used for anything that **holds** data. `wire` cannot retain any data, henceforth it must be driven by continuous assignments.