# How to avoid Inferred latches in ASM chart verilog?

Tags: verilog

I don't understand how to avoid inferred latches in my design of ASM
Here's my code.

```
module ASM (
input[7:0] SW,
input Start, Reset, Clock,
output reg Led,
output reg[3:0] result);

reg[2:0] state, next_state;
reg[7:0] A;
wire Done;

parameter S1 = 3'd1;
parameter S2 = 3'd2;
parameter S3 = 3'd3;
parameter S4 = 3'd4;
parameter S5 = 3'd5;
parameter S6 = 3'd6;

always @(posedge Clock)
begin
    if (!Reset)
        state <= next_state;
    else
        state <= S1;
end

always @(state, Start, A)
begin

    case(state)
    S1: begin
        if (Start)
            next_state = S2;
        else
            next_state = S1;
    end
    S2: begin //check A == 0
        if (A == 8'd0)
            next_state = S6; //done
        else
            next_state = S3;//check A0
    end
    S3: begin //check A0
        if (A[0])
            next_state = S4; //result++
        else
            next_state = S5; //A>>1
    end
    S4: begin //result++
        next_state = S5;
    end
    S5: begin //A>>1
        next_state = S2;
    end     
    S6: begin //done
        if (Start)
            next_state = S6;
        else
            next_state = S1;
    end
    default: begin
        next_state = S1;
    end     
    endcase
end

always @(state, SW)
begin
    //result = 4'b0;
    //A = 8'd0;
    //Led = 1'b0;   
    case (state)
    S1: begin
        A = SW;
        result = 4'b0;
        Led = 1'b0; 
    end
    S2: begin

    end
    S3: begin

    end
    S4: begin
        result <= result + 4'd1;
    end
    S5: begin
        A = A >> 1;
    end     
    S6: begin
        Led = 1'b1;
    end     
    default: begin
        result = 4'b0;
        Led = 1'b0;     
    end 
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

I understand that i should initialize variables "A", "result" and "led" before "case" statement in second "always" block. But if do this every time when "always" block is active I loose my previous results of variables and assign them again to initial values and thus whole design is wrong. So that I can't avoid latches and simply shouldn't initialize these variables. But latches is bad practice. So can you explain how i should change code to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the behaviour you want to get (only change for certain inputs and keep it's value otherwise) is that of a latch. If you want to avoid latches and have variables with memory use a synchronous always block.

```
always @(posedge Clock)
begin 
    case (next_state)
    S1: begin
        A <= SW;
        result <= 4'b0;
        Led <= 1'b0; 
    end
    S2, S3: begin

    end
    S4: begin
        result <= result + 4'd1;
    end
    S5: begin
        A <= A >> 1;
    end     
    S6: begin
        Led <= 1'b1;
    end     
    default: begin
        result <= 4'b0;
        Led <= 1'b0;     
    end 
    endcase
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A synthesizer only cares about your sensitivity list for synchronous logic. `@(state, SW)` only triggers on specific variables in simulation. The synthesizer essentially sees `@(state, SW, result)`. This is way `@*` (and the synonymous `@(*)`) is preferred for combination logic and intentional latches.

For detail about inferred latches read: [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition.can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22459413/1959732)

For your case you should make the block synchronous. Change `@(state, SW)` to `@(posedge Clock)`. To reduce the timing delay, change `case (state)` to `case (next_state)` in the same always block. You should use non-blocking to assign `A`, `result`, and `Led`. You may want to add a reset condtion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why should i use non-blocking assignment in this particular case? I see no difference in desing when I use blocking assignment.

Comment: It is a good coding practice. Synchronous logic and intentional latches should be assigned with non-blocking to reduce the risk of race conditions in simulations. Synthesis doesn't care. http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The latches are inferred from the second case statement in your example. The reason is that all 3 variables are assigned in under some conditions (S1) and not assigned under others (S2,S3,...), meaning that they keep their old values in such cases. This is a typical latch behavior. Therefore you have inferred latches.

I do not think that this statement is good for fixing in any case. You have a bunch of error in it, using operations which should be done in synchronous blocks only, like `A = A >> 1` or mixing blocking and non-blocking assignments. It is not a way to design a state machine. So, look at @Hans's Lehnert  answer to get an idea.