# getting FFGEN from Verilog Synthesizer

Tags: verilog, synthesis

Whenever I pass the following behavioral code through Design Vision synthesizer, I get the FFGEN instances, meaning the synthesizer is treating my logic as having latch, even though it's supposed to be completely combinational.

Code:

```
module decoder(input  [1:0] Op,
input  [5:0] Funct,

output reg[9:0] controls);

    // Main Decoder
 always @(*)  begin
    case(Op)
    // Data-processing immediate
    2'b00: if (Funct[5]) controls = 10'b0000101001;
    // Data-processing register
    else controls = 10'b0000001001;
    // LDR
    2'b01: if (Funct[0]) controls = 10'b0001111000;
    // STR
    else controls = 10'b1001110100;
    // B
    2'b10: controls = 10'b0110100010;
    endcase
 end
endmodule
```

Could anyone advise how to modify the code so that I can use my own design library for the output structural verilog

Comment: Also a search with the keywords 'Verilog' and 'Latch' gives 121 hits most of which are applicable to your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition.can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i)

Comment: Hello.. thank you everyone should much for replying. Yes specifying all the cases did the trick of removing latch logic. But I still get Flup flop logic. I do no understand how that makes sense. Can't this logic be represented purely combinationally ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common mistake to make. Your case items do not cater for all the possible values of the case statement expression `Op`.

You can fix it by adding a `default` statement towards the end, after your last case item.

For further reading, there is an excellent answer by Greg here - [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition.can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i)

Comment: @LearningCurve you should not be seeing any sequential logic generated for this. I am not sure why you are seeing it but you can share your updated code for us to take a look

Answer (score -2):

Just keep in mind of all the dependencies and enlist them inside the sensitive list. Also, as mentioned by [toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805024/getting-ffgen-from-verilog-synthesizer), don't forget to add the default case in your case statement as the last case for it.

Comment: I know that (*) is appropriate but still, keeping the sensitive list makes it simpler to avoid FFGEN error.