# Warning: Inferring latch for variable 'w_addra_t' (in Verilog/SystemVerilog with FOR loop)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, inferred-type

I have an inferred latch problem after synthesis when I designed a simple dual port RAM block. Due to large code size, I have just embedded this *always* block code as follows:

```
integer i;
always_latch
begin
    for (i=0;i<NUM_RAMS;i=i+1) begin
        if (ena_t == 1) begin   
            w_addra_t[i] = w_addra[i];
        end
        else begin
            w_addra_t[bank_addra[i]] = w_addra[i];
        end
    end
end
```

My RAM block includes *NUM_RAMS* numbers of banks. The addresses of respective input data are stored in *w_addra*.

Data with given *w_addra* addresses are scrambled into *w_addra_t* depend on the values of respective *bank_addra* (depend on access pattern) when *ena_t* = 0.

I tried to replace *for* loop with *if...else*, *switch...case*, *generate* but the problem is same. With different *always* block in my code that the left-side is with only *w_addra_t[i]* in both *if.else* of *ena_t*, there is no error.

I would like to get your suggestion if you have any idea. I did look for similar issue but getting no results.

Thanks very much :)

Comment: not sure what exactly your question is. Which inferred latch you are talking about? There could be a latch in the second part of the if statement unless synhtesis detects memory. if you are missing the second part, then synthesis just figures out that your ena_t never gets any value but '1'. You need to check your logic for this signal.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid latch?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I got a synthesis report about warning an inferring latch (edited in the title), which I suppose to make the implementation runs wrongly. And I want to avoid this warning, which has no warning when the left-side assignment is with only w_addra_t[i] in both if and else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the entries for `bank_addra` are not guaranteed to be unique. If two or more entries hold the same values then an index hole is created for `w_addra_t`; which will infer a latch.

Here are three possible solution:

1. Functionally guaranteed that `bank_addra` entries will have unique values, then the synthesizer should not infer a latch. This can be challenging.
2. Move the address variation from the LHS to the RHS so that each index of `w_addra_t` is guaranteed to be assigned a value. Ex change `w_addra_t[bank_addra[i]] = w_addra[i];` to `w_addra_t[i] = w_addra[bank_addra_lookup[i]];`.
3. Assign all entries of `w_addra_t` to a known value (constant, flip-flop, or deterministic value) before other logic. You can put this default assignment at the top of your always block (option 1 example) or above the logic where the latches were about to be inferred (option 2 example). This is the simplest solution to implement assuming it still satisfies relational requirements with your other code.

   ```
   // NOTE: SystemVerilog supports full array assignments (Verilog requires a for-loop)
   always_comb
   begin
     w_addra_t = '{default:'0}; // <-- default assignment : option 1
     if (ena_t == 1) begin
       w_addra_t = w_addra; 
     end
     else begin
       w_addra_t = w_addra_t_ff; // <-- default assignment : option 2
       for (i=0;i<NUM_RAMS;i=i+1) begin
         w_addra_t[bank_addra[i]] = w_addra[i];
       end
     end
   end
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
     w_addra_t_ff <= w_addra_t; // assuming w_addra_t should hold it current values
   end
   ```

---

TL;DR
`always_latch` is a SystemVerilog keyword to identify explicit latches. Some tools will auto-waive the warning when the keyword is used, but will throw an error/warning if the keyword is used and a latch is not detected.

If you know it should be combinational logic, then use the `always_comb` SystemVerilog keyword. With `always_comb`, if the synthesis detects a latch then it should report an error.

Read related question:
[What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition. Can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22459413/1959732)

Comment: In my case, assign a default value (option 1) before loop operation helps remove the inferring latch warning. However I am confused if that assignment is always called in "always" block or only at the first time. Thank you once again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem by changing to

```
int i
always_comb
```

instead. Perhaps the tool gets sad when you use a 4-state variable like integer?