# 8bit ALU line 46: Can not simplify operator DIV

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Hello guys I just wanted to ask how to debug this one in line 46 in says "Can not simplify operator DIV." in Verilog Module (Xilinx). Thank you in advance for the tip and help :))

[image: Synthesize Failed]

[image: line 46: Can not simplify operator DIV.]

Here's the code of my 8bit ALU

```
module alu_8fctn (a, b, opcode, rslt, rslt_mul);
input [3:0] a, b;
input [2:0] opcode;
output [3:0] rslt;
output [7:0] rslt_mul;
wire [3:0] a, b; //inputs are wire
wire [2:0] opcode;
reg [3:0] rslt; //outputs are reg
reg [7:0] rslt_mul;
//define operation codes
parameter add_op = 3'b000,
            sub_op = 3'b001,
            mul_op = 3'b010,
            div_op = 3'b011,
            and_op = 3'b100,
            or_op = 3'b101,
            xor_op = 3'b110,
            xnor_op = 3'b111;
//perform the operations
always @(a or b or opcode)
begin
case (opcode)
            add_op : rslt = a + b;
            sub_op : rslt = a - b;
            mul_op : rslt_mul = a * b;
            div_op : rslt = a / b;
            and_op : rslt = a & b;
            or_op : rslt = a | b;
            xor_op : rslt = a ^ b;
            xnor_op: rslt = a ^~ b;
            default: rslt = 8'b0000_0000;
endcase
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Xilinx appears to have trouble with `a / b`. Synthesizers can have a hard time optimizing with variable divisors; especially if they can be zero.

Xilinx should have some predefined modules for division (if not you can always make your own)

```
wire [3:0] rslt_div;
<XilinxPrividedDividerModuleName> div ( rslt_div, a, b);
always @*
  ...
  div_op : rslt = a / b;
  ...
```

---

Other issue:
`rslt` and `rslt_mul` are inferred latches because they are not assign in all conditions. In `mul_op`  and `rslt_mul` is only assigned in `mul_op` and that is the only condition `rslt` is not assigned.

Refer to [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition. Can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22459413/1959732)

Simple solution is give the `rslt` and `rslt_mul` an initial/default value before the case statement.

```
always @*
begin
  rslt = 4'h0;
  rslt_mul = 8'h00;
  case (opcode)
    // ... you other code
  endcase
end
```

---

Also note that `always @(a or b or opcode)` is the Verilog-1995 way of writing a sensitivity list. Since Verilog-2001 the preferred way is `always @*` (or the synonymous `always @(*)`). SystemVerilog goes a step further with `always_comb` where a good tool should flag an error if a latch is inferred.

You may also want to consider ANSI style module headers (also available since Verilog-2001) which is less verbose and less prone to typos then the Verilog-1995 module header style.

```
module alu_8fctn (
  input [3:0] a, b,
  input [2:0] opcode,
  output reg [3:0] rslt,
  output reg [7:0] rslt_mul );

  //define operation codes
  parameter add_op = 3'b000,
  ...
```

Comment: Hello Greg I still got an error in "line 48: Can not simplify operator DIV."

Comment: Hello Greg I still got an error on "line 44 Could not find module/primitive" may I know what type of XilinxPrividedDividerModuleName it should be. Thank you :))

Comment: I don’t have Xilinx, so I don’t know the specific division module in the tool library. You have to look it up or write your own.