# Vivado Not Creating Schematic after Synthesis

Tags: verilog, vivado, synthesis

I am able to simulate my cpu with no errors and received the waveforms I expected. So I went to run the synthesis and I received my foreplaning, i/o planning, and etc. However it did not produce a schematic.

There are many warnings after synthesis:
[image: warnings]

Here is my Verilog code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module CPU(
    input clk
    );
    
    wire [31:0] Mux4_PC;
    wire [31:0] PC_Adder_InstMem;
    wire [31:0] Adder_Mux4;
    wire [31:0] Instruction;
    wire [31:0] qa_Mux;
    wire [31:0] qb_ALU;
    wire [31:0] mux_ALU;
    wire [31:0] ALU_d;
    wire [1:0] pcsrc;
    wire [3:0] aluc;
    wire shift;
    wire wreg;
    wire zOut;
    
    PC PC(clk, Mux4_PC, PC_Adder_InstMem);
    InstMem InstMem(PC_Adder_InstMem, Instruction);
    PCadder PCadder(PC_Adder_InstMem, Adder_Mux4);
    ControlUnit ControlUnit(Instruction[31:26], Instruction[5:0],aluc, pcsrc, wreg, shift);
    regfile regfile(.d(ALU_d), .rna(Instruction[25:21]), .rnb(Instruction[20:16]), .wn(Instruction[15:11]), .we(wreg), .clk(clk), .clrn(_), .qa(qa_Mux), .qb(qb_ALU));
    shiftMux shiftMux(shift, qa_Mux, Instruction[10:6], mux_ALU);
    ALU ALU(.a(mux_ALU), .b(qb_ALU), .aluc(aluc), .r(ALU_d), .zOut(zOut));
    input4Mux input4Mux(.in0(Adder_Mux4), .in1(_), .in2(_), .in3(_), .pcsrc(pcsrc), .out(Mux4_PC));
    
endmodule

module ControlUnit(
    input [5:0] op, func,
    
    output reg [3:0] aluc,
    output reg [1:0] pcsrc,
    output reg wreg,
    output reg shift
    );
    
    always @(op, func)
    begin
        case(op)
        0:  // R-FORMAT
            case(func)
            0:  // SLL
            begin
                aluc <= 4'b0011;
                pcsrc <= 2'b00;
                wreg <= 1;
                shift <= 1;
            end
            
            34: // SUB
            begin
                aluc <= 4'b0100;
                pcsrc <= 2'b00;
                wreg <= 1;
                shift <= 0;
            end
            
            37: // OR
            begin
                aluc <= 4'b0101;
                pcsrc <= 2'b00;
                wreg <= 1;
                shift <= 0;
            end
            
            endcase
        endcase
    end
    
endmodule

module ALU(
    input [31:0] a, b,
    input [3:0] aluc,
    
    output reg [31:0] r,
    output reg zOut
    );
    
    always @(aluc, a, b)
    begin
        case(aluc)
            0:  // ADD
                r <= a + b;
            3:  // SLL
                r <= b << a;
            4:  // SUB
                r <= a - b;
            5:  // OR
                r <= a | b;
        endcase
    end
    
endmodule

module regfile(
    input [31:0] d, // data of write port
    input [4:0] rna, // reg # of read port A
    input [4:0] rnb, // reg # of read port B
    input [4:0] wn, // reg # of write port
    input we, // write enable
    input clk, clrn,

    output [31:0] qa, qb // read ports A and B
    );
    
    reg [31:0] register [1:31]; // 31 32-bit registers
    assign qa = (rna == 0)? 0 : register[rna]; // read port A, qa = 0 if rna==0 is true, qa = register[rna] if rna==0 is false
    assign qb = (rnb == 0)? 0 : register[rnb]; // read port B
    integer i;
    
    initial 
    begin
        register[1] = 32'ha00000aa;
        register[2] = 32'h10000011;
        register[3] = 32'h20000022;
        register[4] = 32'h30000033;
        register[5] = 32'h40000044;
        register[6] = 32'h50000055;
        register[7] = 32'h60000066;
        register[8] = 32'h70000077;
        register[9] = 32'h80000088;
        register[10] = 32'h90000099;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk or negedge clrn) // write port
    begin 
        if (!clrn)
        begin
            for (i = 1; i < 32; i = i + 1)
            begin
                register[i] <= 0; // reset
            end
        end
        
        else if ((wn != 0) && we) // not reg[0] & enabled
        begin
            register[wn] <= d; // write d to reg[wn]
        end
    end
endmodule

module InstMem(
    input [31:0]a,
    
    output reg [31:0] do
    );
    
    reg [7:0] instruc [1:12];
    
    initial 
    begin
        instruc[1] = 8'h01;     //sub $t0, $t1, $a0
        instruc[2] = 8'h24;
        instruc[3] = 8'h40;
        instruc[4] = 8'h22;
        instruc[5] = 8'h01;     //or $a2, $t2, $t1
        instruc[6] = 8'h49;
        instruc[7] = 8'h30;
        instruc[8] = 8'h25;
        instruc[9] = 8'h00;     //sll $t0, $a1, 15
        instruc[10] = 8'h05;
        instruc[11] = 8'h43;
        instruc[12] = 8'hc0;
    end
    
    always @*
    begin
        do [31:24] <= instruc[a+1]; 
        do [23:16] <= instruc[a+2];
        do [15:8] <= instruc[a+3];
        do [7:0] <= instruc[a+4];
    end
    
endmodule 

module PC(
    input clk,
    input [31:0] in,
    
    output reg [31:0] out
    );
    
    initial
    begin
        out <= 32'h00000000;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        out <= in;
    end

endmodule

module PCadder(
    input [31:0] PCin,
    
    output reg [31:0] PCadd
    );
    
    always @(PCin)
    begin
        PCadd <= PCin + 32'h00000004;
    end
endmodule 

module shiftMux(
    input shift,  
    input [31:0] qa, 
    input [4:0] sa,
    
    output reg [31:0] shiftMuxOut
    );
    
    always @(qa,sa,shift)
    begin
        if (shift == 1)
        begin
            shiftMuxOut [31:5] <= 27'b0;
            shiftMuxOut [4:0] <= sa;
        end
        else
        begin
            shiftMuxOut <= qa;
        end
    end
    
endmodule 

module input4Mux(
    input [31:0] in0, in1, in2, in3,
    input [1:0] pcsrc,
    
    output reg [31:0] out
    );
    
    always @(in0, in1, in2, in3, pcsrc)
    begin
        case(pcsrc)
            0:
                out <= in0;
            1:
                out <= in1;
            2:
                out <= in2;
            3:
                out <= in3;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

I am able to get a RTL Analysis Schematic however I really need the Synthesis Schematic. Is something causing it to become unsynthesizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning messages explained:

- The entire design is being optimized/logic-trimmed by synthesis because the top level module (CPU) has no outputs, and almost no inputs.
  The internal variables in the CPU module are hanging in space (not connected to the top level module outputs) therefore synthesis removes them.

  The tool is indicating that is is performing logic trimming in the warnings:
  '... has no load'
  '... is unconnected'
  '... unused and will be removed'.

  With the entire design optimized away, there is nothing which could be used to create a schematic.

  To fix this, add outputs to the top level and connect the internal nodes to the top level.
  The design also has no inputs except clk.
  Also add the missing inputs.

Like this:

```
module CPU(
  input   clk,
  // inputs
  input   wire [3:0] aluc,    
  // more inputs ...
  // outputs
  output  wire [31:0] ALU_d
  );

  // local variables
  wire [31:0] Mux4_PC;
  wire [31:0] PC_Adder_InstMem;
  wire [31:0] Adder_Mux4;
  wire [31:0] Instruction;
  wire [31:0] qa_Mux;
  wire [31:0] qb_ALU;
  wire [31:0] mux_ALU;
  // wire [31:0] ALU_d;
  wire [1:0] pcsrc;
  // wire [3:0] aluc;
  wire shift;
  wire wreg;
  wire zOut;
```

- The latch inference message is a separate issue which should be addressed
  (unless the design intent is to infer latches).
  This is a common often asked/answered issue.
  Here is an answer which explains:
  [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition. Can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i)
  In your code the case statements `default :` statements are missing.
- The message about parallel synthesis is the tool indicating it will not optimize further because the design is already optimized away.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quick example of how to perform "To fix this, add outputs to the top level and connect the internal nodes to the top level.
The design also has no inputs except clk.
Also add the missing inputs."